# Real time area map HTML 5 + AKKA + Websocket

Tags: html, websocket, html5-canvas, akka

I have business requirement for real time application in that moving vehicle transmits its position (lat,lang) to server and I need to show area that is covered by vehicle in real time on browser (possibly overlay on Google maps) as vehicle moves within fixed large area. The area can be in any shape and vehicle moving direction can be anything.

I'm wondering what will be efficient way to implement this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what AKKA is, but we built a very similar solution for a hackathon, it's described here: http://blog.kaazing.com/2013/04/26/a-connected-car-project-navigation-sharing-with-websocket/.

Answer (score 0):

It's a year late, but this seems like it fits the bill:
https://github.com/bmdhacks/akka_whiteboard